# Sharepoint authentication with username only

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication, single-sign-on

I currently have an MVC website that uses forms authentication.

In this website I can automatically log in a user by simply having a GUID that corresponds to their UserId in the aspnet_Membership table. All I do is query the table, then using their username I simply have forms authentication set the auth cookie.

I currently use:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false)
```

But can optionally also use:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false, "/")
```

Now, I need to do something similar to this, but on SharePoint. SP does have access to my membership tables.

However, it seems that SP uses SecurityTokens for the validation:

```
        SecurityToken token = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url), formsClaimsAuthenticationProvider.MembershipProvider, formsClaimsAuthenticationProvider.RoleProvider, strUsername, strPassword);   

        if (null != token)   
        {   
            EstablishSessionWithToken(token);   
            Response.Redirect(strSource);
        }
```

Is there a way to get this token by simply providing the username, without the password?

Comment: I just realized that stackexchange has a site specific to sharepoint (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com). Is there any way to move this question there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure, but you can create your own login page when you're using FBA (forms based authentication). In that custom login page you can do whatever you want to authenticate the user.

- [Creating a Custom Login Page for FBA in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/08/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-fba-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Of course you will have to [configure SharePoint first for FBA](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mahesm/archive/2010/04/07/configure-forms-based-authentication-fba-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx) which is [quite a "complicated"](http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/configuring-forms-base-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-using-iis7/) process.

If that isn't enough and the SQLMembershipProvider is not what you are looking for, you could even write your own membership provider / role provider which does exactly what you want it to do: work with GUIDs etc.